# Connected to Phantom 4 Pro but not receiving video

Tags: dji-sdk

I have followed the panorama demo example and am connected to the drone. I'm getting a DJIAircraft with the correct model and also a DJICamera but the video never starts (no image & didReceiveVideoData is never called). If i switch to the DJI GO 4 app i can see the live video feed. Any ideas?

```
//
//  CaptureViewController.swift
//

// MARK: - Source https://developer.dji.com/mobile-sdk/documentation/ios-tutorials/PanoDemo.html

import UIKit
import VideoPreviewer
import ToastSwiftFramework

class CaptureViewController: UIViewController, DJISDKManagerDelegate, DJICameraDelegate, DJIPlaybackDelegate, DJIMissionManagerDelegate, DJIFlightControllerDelegate {
    @IBOutlet var fpvPreviewView: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tabBarItem.title = "CAPTURE".localized

        VideoPreviewer.instance().setView(fpvPreviewView)
        self.registerApp()
    }

    func registeredAppWithError(error: Error?) {
        guard error == nil else {
            makeToast("Error registering app \(error)")

            return
        }

        VideoPreviewer.instance().start()
    }

    //MARK: - DJI Delegate

    func registerApp() {
        DJISDKManager.registerApp("******************", with: self)
    }

    func sdkManagerDidRegisterAppWithError(_ error: Error?) {
        guard error == nil else {
            makeToast("Error registering SDK Manager \(error)")

            return
        }

        DJISDKManager.startConnectionToProduct()

        makeToast("Registered app with DJISDKManager")
    }

    func camera(product: DJIBaseProduct?) -> DJICamera? {
        guard let aircraft = DJISDKManager.product() as? DJIAircraft else { return nil }

        return aircraft.camera
    }

    func sdkManagerProductDidChange(from oldProduct: DJIBaseProduct?, to newProduct: DJIBaseProduct?) {
        makeToast("Found \(newProduct?.model ?? "")")

        guard let camera = camera(product: newProduct) else {
            makeToast("No camera!")

            return
        }

        makeToast("Camera \(camera.displayName)")

        camera.delegate = self
        camera.playbackManager?.delegate = self
    }

    var receivedVideo = false

    func camera(_ camera: DJICamera, didReceiveVideoData videoBuffer: UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>, length size: Int) {
        makeToast("Receiving video!")

        VideoPreviewer.instance().push(videoBuffer, length: Int32(size))
    }

    func playbackManager(_ playbackManager: DJIPlaybackManager, didUpdate playbackState: DJICameraPlaybackState) {
        makeToast("PlaybackState: \(playbackState.playbackMode)")
    }
}
```

Comment: i have a same problem, do you find it?

Comment: Yes just restart remote controller, bridge device and your development device and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I know its very late but we faced similar issue in our App, the problem is when DJI drone is connected  then at the same time we do not get the camera's instance at the time of connection . Add a delay of 5-10 secs after the connection. I have done the similar thing and it is working for every drone now.

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(7 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))), dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                    let camera = ConnectedDroneManager.sharedDroneInstance.fetchCamera()
                camera?.delegate = self
                camera?.playbackManager?.delegate = self

})
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You should start the video streaming after your app connected to the DJI product. Putting `VideoPreviewer.instance().start()` into the `sdkManagerProductDidChange` delegate method will solve the problem.

```
func sdkManagerDidRegisterAppWithError(_ error: Error?) {
    guard error == nil else {
        makeToast("Error registering SDK Manager \(error)")

        return
    }

    DJISDKManager.startConnectionToProduct()
    VideoPreviewer.instance().start()

    makeToast("Registered app with DJISDKManager")
}
```

Answer (score -2):

The DJI's iOS PanoDemo is written in Objective-C, I have tried it on a Phantom 4 Pro, the demo app can show the live video feed successfully. Seems like you are writing your own DJI SDK app using Swift.

In the code you show above, I think you haven't registered the app successfully. In the `registerApp()` fun, you pass "******************" in the DJISDKManager.registerApp() method, which is not correct, you should create an App key using your Xcode's bundle ID on DJI Developer Website User Center: https://developer.dji.com/user/apps/, then paste it in the `registerApp()` method.

For more, you can follow the DJI Swift Sample Code on Github: https://github.com/dji-sdk/Mobile-SDK-iOS/tree/master/Sample%20Code/SwiftSampleCode to learn how to make your own DJI SDK app. Hope this help!

Comment: Of course, because everyone posts their API key on StackOverflow. Obviously i used a registered app key instead of ******************.